# How to access <item> from <string-array> resource in an android XML?

Tags: android, xml

I have a xml file (/res/xml/setting.xml) for PreferenceActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Main Settings">
            <ListPreference
                android:title="Background Image"
                android:summary="Set the background image"
                android:key="key_background"
                android:entries="@array/background"
                android:entryValues="@array/background_values" 
                android:defaultValue="winter.png" /> 
        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then I have another xml file "/res/values/string.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="background">
        <item>Winter</item>
        <item>Desert</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="background_values">
        <item>winter.png</item>
        <item>desert.png</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

See ListPreference in setting.xml, I want `android:defaultValue` to be set with `winter.png`. But I also don't want to be set with hardcoded/constant value in the xml, so I tried with various values such as "`@array/background_values/0`", "`@array/background_values[0]`", etc...but all failed.

So, the questions are:

1. What is the correct syntax for accesing an item of string-array resource in other xml?
2. How to make sure if the `android:defaultValue` is working?
3. Is there any documentation about the `@array` syntax? I can't found any.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) gives no way for resource reference to `string-array` in XML, not to metion its items.
2. You can clear your app's data, reinstall and open your app, go to your settings screen, then the `defaultValue` will go to your shared prefereces file. If `defaultValue` matches one of the items, it will be selected.

BTW, you can change your items in string-array to reference to string to avoid hardcoding.

Comment: **References to string** is not hardcoded value, why not use it?

Comment: I see, so I can create a <string> resource for the winter.jpg (let'say I give it id=default_background) and winter.jpg in background_values <string-array> is changed to @string/default_background. I found it a little not intuitive, but I guess it's the only way to type winter.jpg once in xml.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use the index of the value you want from your array android:defaultValue="0"</strike>

The above code worked only because i am using numbers inside my string array values, it is not because of index.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to test if the android:defaultValue is working?

Comment: You may want to 'Clear data' of your application to reset preferences to default. You can do it on the phone Settings. (Also please don't forget to upvote and/or mark this as an answer if it helps you)

Comment: Try to select a different value other than the default. Then go to Settings and Clear the data of your app. The next time you open your app it must display the default value.

Comment: The android:defaultValue="0" doesn't work. The result is the list showed up with no option selected at all (of course I already cleared the application data). Screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/device20120418175643.jpg/

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense if we can put number "0", "1",...etc. How if there is "0" value in a background_values list? Let's say I change the "desert.png" to "0" in background_values string-array.

Comment: You must indicate the explicit value. `android:defaultValue="Day"` or use a string resource id.

Comment: In reply to your modified post: I see, but I don't want to rename my filename to "0", "1", etc. I guess there is no way except to set android:defaultValue to hardcoded value ("winter.png").

Comment: Yes there is a way. Check this page from android devs: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/xml/default_values.html Preference with default values

Comment: Nope, it's not what I want. I want to access/refer the item value directly from the string-array (@array). That example from android dev uses a string resource (@string) whose the value already exist in the string-array.

Answer (score 0):

1- Define a separate file for arrays (res/values/arrays.xml)

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<resources>
<string-array name="settings_order_by_labels">
    <item>label1</item>
    <item>label2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="settings_order_by_values">
    <item>value1</item>
    <item>value2</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

2- use this arrays in Preference xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:title="@string/settings_title">

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="value1"
    android:entries="@array/settings_order_by_labels"
    android:entryValues="@array/settings_order_by_values"
    android:key="order_by"
    android:title="Order By" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```