# How to reference to a string array element in XML (android)

Tags: android, xml

How to access an element of a string array

```
<string-array name="contextMenuItems">
    <item>Edit</item>
    <item>Info</item>
    <item>Delete</item>        
</string-array>
```

from another resource xml file

```
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/Edit"
        android:title="@string/contextMenuItems" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Info"
        android:title="@array/contextMenuItems" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it can't be done according to the people in this similar post.

[How to access <item> from <string-array> resource in an android XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205316/how-to-access-item-from-string-array-resource-in-an-android-xml?answertab=active)

My suggestion would be to populate the menu items with some Java code when loading the particular activity or use separate @string values for each menu item.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to re-organize the string resource like below

in the file strings.xml,

```
<string name="label_edit">Edit</string>
<string name="label_info">Info</string>
<string name="label_delete">Delete</string>
```

in the file arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="contextMenuItems">
        <item>@string/label_edit</item>
        <item>@string/label_info</item>
        <item>@string/label_delete</item>        
</string-array>
```

in the file menu.xml

```
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/Edit" android:title="@string/label_edit" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Info" android:title="@array/label_info" />
</menu>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override a function:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
       {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case R.id.Edit:
                //Handled [0]
                return true;
                case R.id.Info:
                    // Handled [1]
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        }
```